# Fix Management About Us Section

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

In Dave Fullerton's section change "the" to "them":

> He's also tasked with helping **the** grow and evolve while keeping it
>   rooted in our mission to serve all the world's developers. David
>   joined Stack Overflow in 2010 as a Development Team Lead before
>   assuming a leadership role in 2012 as Vice President of Engineering.
>   David was promoted to President in 2018. Prior to joining Stack
>   Overflow, David worked at Fog Creek Software, where he began his
>   career as an intern and then as a developer on the FogBugz team. He
>   has a BA in computer science from Dartmouth College, and holds strong
>   opinions on working remotely, private offices, and engineering
>   management in general

In Guy Zerega's section fix the following sentence:

> He's owned his own companies and held various sales **and leadership
>   across a wide range of companies** from bootstrap startup to well
>   established corporate brands. Guy has a BA in journalism from NYU
>   where he was an Academic All American on the Wrestling Team.

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/company/management